# Protecting a switching regulator in a 12v automotive system

Tags: circuit-protection, varistor

I'm using a [MaxLinear XRP7659](https://www.maxlinear.com/ds/xrp7659.pdf) as a 12v -> 5v regulator in my design. The circuit has an average power usage of 80mA @ 12v and a maximum usage of ~500mA @ 12v.

I have a 750mA fuse on VIN, along with a 100uF 63v capacitor and a common mode choke (both to clean up noise).

I am considering using a Varistor to protect the XRP7659 from destructive transients, but I'm confused about their specs.

1. Is the Varistor even the best way to deal with transcients?
2. The regulator is rated for an absolute maximum of 20v. This means that I should use a Varistor with a maximum clamping voltage of 20v, correct?
3. Why is it that [certain varistors](https://www.littelfuse.com/%7E/media/electronics/datasheets/varistors/littelfuse_varistor_auml_datasheet.pdf.pdf) have a clamping voltage of 2x their rated DC voltage? In my limited experience, I haven't seen many regulators with that wide of an input range, so I have a I feeling that I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: The answer depends on whether you are on the switched system or not; if you are on the battery (unswitched) system there can be transients of up to (IIRC) over 80V during load dump.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using a [TVS diode](https://www.littelfuse.com/%7E/media/electronics/datasheets/tvs_diodes/littelfuse_tvs_diode_smdj_datasheet.pdf.pdf) instead of a varistor. Clamping is faster and more effective.

[image: tvs13]